# why 'system.web.ui.scriptmanager' does not contain a definition for 'registerpostbackcontrol'?

Tags: c#, asp.net

download button inside tabpanel doesnt work.. i try this method :

```
  ImageButton lb = e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton1") as ImageButton;  
            if(lb != null)
            ScriptManager.RegisterPostbackControl(lb);
            int index = ((GridViewRow)((ImageButton)e.CommandArgument).Parent.Parent).RowIndex;
```

but why it says 'system.web.ui.scriptmanager' does not contain a definition for 'registerpostbackcontrol' ? i already use system.web.ui on header... please help

Answer (score 1):

You must add the `System.Web.Extensions.dll` reference to your project.

If you already did that, and the problem persists, ensure that your `ScriptManager` control inside your page doesn't have the ID `ScriptManager`, because C# will try to use it instead of the class.